# Как подключить сервис $mdToast c Angular Material в TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Как подключить сервис $mdToast c Angular Material в TypeScript?

Comment: [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/md-toast), или какой ангуляр имеется ввиду?

Comment: вот этот: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdToast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение такое: взял d.ts от сюда: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/angular-material

и в самом приложении написал:

```
import 'angular-material';
import 'angular-animate';
import 'angular-aria';
```

И в зависимости модуля добавил 'ngMaterial'

```
export const appModule: ng.IModule = angular.module('ts', [
    'ngMaterial'
])
```